# With Python, how to update multiple Mysql records with a long list of tuples?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python list that contains hundreds of tuples, and I want to update hundreds of corresponding records in a Mysql table with the data in the tuples. This is what my list of tuples looks like (shortened here):

`updated_dates = [(1, '1997-12-29'), (2, '1998-01-05'), (3, '1998-01-12'), (4, '1998-01-19'), (5, '1998-01-26'), (6, '1998-02-02'), (7, '1998-02-09'), (8, '1998-02-16')]`

Here is my code in which I attempt to update the Mysql records where the first value in each tuple corresponds with the id of each row to update:

```
for id_, date_ in updated_dates:
      sql = "UPDATE table SET date = %s WHERE id = %s"
      db_cursor.executemany(sql, (date_, id_))
      db_connection.commit()
```

The error I receive is:

```
for id_, date_ in updated_dates:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am sorry to ask a bad question, but I have spent much time on this without resolution. How may I update all my Mysql records with the data from the tuples in my list?

Thank you so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vir for his feedback. After more search, trial, and error, cursor.executemany actually basically is a loop on its own, so a for loop doesn't work and is not needed at all.

I flipped the position of the key and value in the tuples, so the id was second in the tuple, and this works:

```
updated_dates = [('1997-12-29', 1), ('1998-01-05', 2), ('1998-01-12', 3), ('1998-01-19', 4), ...etc]

sql = "UPDATE table SET date = %s WHERE id = %s"
db_cursor.executemany(sql, updated_dates)
db_connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2, you can use `iteritems()`

```
for id_, date_ in updated_dates.iteritems():
```

Or for Python 3, you can use `items()`.

```
for id_, date_ in updated_dates.items():
```